# HTML table with JSON

Tags: html, angularjs, json, html-table

I have a different format of JSON below, I need to put it with HTML table and display it. I need to do this in AngularJS. I tried with normal JSON format it was working fine but for this JSON it's not working. This example is for indexing search, so I need to maintain JSON like that.

For example:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
       <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
       <td>{{x.City}}</td>
       <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
       </tr>
 </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names =[
  {
    "Name" : "Max Joe",
    "City" : "Lulea",
    "Country" : "Sweden"
  },
    {
    "Name" : "Manish",
    "City" : "Delhi",
    "Country" : "India"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Koniglich",
    "City" : "Barcelona",
    "Country" : "Spain"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Wolski",
    "City" : "Arhus",
    "Country" : "Denmark"
  }
];     
});
</script>
    </div>
```

Now I need to do the same thing with the below JSON format:

```js
{
    "data": [
            [
                "1",
                "supply chain Management",
                "https://www.google.co.in/",
                "abc",
                1234567,
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "assdadsddsf",
                "1"

            ],

            [
                "2",
                "Data Tower",
                "https://www.google.co.in/",
                "abc",
                1234567,
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "assdadsddsf",
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "3",
                "Enter business",
                "https://www.google.co.in/",
                "abc",
                1234567,
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "assdadsddsf",
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "4",
                "IOT",
                "https://www.google.co.in/",
                "abc",
                1234567,
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "assdadsddsf",
                "4"
            ],
            [
                "5",
                "Supplys Chain",
                "https://www.google.co.in/",
                "abc",
                1234567,
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "assdadsddsf",
                "5"
            ],
            [
                "6",
                "Supplys Chain",
                "https://www.google.co.in/",
                "abc",
                1234567,
                "abc@gmail.com",
                "assdadsddsf",
                "6"
            ]

        ]
    }
```

Comment: <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data">          <ul>

              <li ng-repeat="x in item">
                  {{x}}
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>      
  </ul>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the second object "dataObj". dataObj.data holds an array of arrays, which is why a simple ng-repeat won't work on it.

dataObj.data[0][0] would return:

```html
  "1",
  "supply chain Management",
  "https://www.google.co.in/",
  "abc",
  1234567,
  "abc@gmail.com",
  "assdadsddsf",
  "1"
```

$scope.names is an array of objects. If you change the dataObj to an array of objects as well, it will work!

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: Actually I need the result in tabular form,which should come from <td></td> and with separate attribute like  <td>{{x[0]}}</td>
       <td>{{x[1]}}</td>
       <td>{{x[2]}}</td> something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>To Access Single Array</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="data in datas">
      <div class="panel-heading">{{data[$index]}} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>To Access all data Array</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="data in datas">
      <div class="panel-heading">{{data}} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AngularFile

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  var data = '{"data": [["1","supply chain Management", "https://www.google.co.in/","abc", 1234567,"abc@gmail.com","assdadsddsf",  "1"  ], [ "2", "Data Tower", "https://www.google.co.in/", "abc", 1234567, "abc@gmail.com", "assdadsddsf", "2" ], ["3","Enter business", "https://www.google.co.in/", "abc", 1234567, "abc@gmail.com","assdadsddsf", "3" ]]}'

  $scope.datas = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Play code here https://jsfiddle.net/ikismail7/2uufzqqh/